# top output: CPU usage > 100%

Tags: linux, top

Here is the [`top`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) output which I gathered:

[image: top output]

I noticed that `top` shows VLC's CPU usage at more than 100%.

Can anybody please explain why `top` is showing those numbers? Is this a bug in `top` or something else?

Comment: It's not lying to you, because your load average is up over 4.  That seems high - try restarting vlc, and do something to free up some memory first.

Comment: Also, I see you're using compiz.  Do you have a good 3d graphics card?  If not, that's probably where all your CPU is going, trying to render a movie onto a 3d surface.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You are in a multi-core/multi-CPU environment and `top` is working in [Irix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IRIX) mode. That means that your process (`vlc`) is performing a computation that keeps 1.2 CPUs/cores busy. That could mean 100%+20%, 60%+60%, etc.

Press 'I' (capital i, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>) to switch to [Solaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Solaris) mode. You get the same value divided by the number of cores/CPUs.

Comment: After you switch out of Irix mode by pressing `I`, you can press `W` to save that as the default configuration if you are root.

Comment: Before you've pressed `W` to have saved those as def. config, you can also press `1` once or twice to get an idea of how exactly CPUs/cores are being loaded. ;)

Comment: what should be concluded if we have a single core machine and `top` displays one of the process as 100% cpu usage. Does this means the machine is hung and no other process will get CPU time.

Comment: @krishna_oza: If that were the case then `top` wouldn't be able to update the list of processes anymore, cause it's a process too. 100% on a single core machine means “no other process requested any CPU time during the measuring interval” (or maybe something did, but was so quick it ended up a measuring error). Most importantly, *when* another process becomes active you should see that 100% value drop in `top` again with the other process getting the remaining share.

Comment: Update on the comments of @AKWF & @poige: I'm not sure whether this was the case in 2012 already, but as of now (2019) `top` will save the configuration file to `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-~/.config}/procps/toprc` if the `W` key is used when running it as regular user.

Comment: THATS A CAPITAL i, LIKE IDIOT, FOR ME SPENDING 5 MINUTES PRESSING LOWERCASE L WONDERING WHY THE HELL IT DOESNT WORK