# javac takes over 200% CPU on RHEL6?

Tags: rhel, top

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [top output: cpu usage > 100%](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34435/top-output-cpu-usage-100)

I don't think I understand what `top` is telling me. I have a `javac` process that says that it's taking over 200% of CPU. That's in the process line. But at the top, I see:

```
Cpu(s):  5.2%us, 19.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 74.0%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.5%si,  0.0%st
```

which is acceptable. What is that CPU % that's being reported to me in the process lines. It always freaks me out when I see it, then I look at the top and I feel a little bit better.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34435/top-output-cpu-usage-100